# Вытеснение из-под fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Имеется страница, состоящая из двух основных блоков (`.header` и `.main`). У блока `.header` установлен `position: fixed`.

Проблема состоит в том, что блок `.main` впадает в блок `.header`. Т.е. заезжает под блок `.header`.

```css
body { margin: 5px; }

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px red, inset -2px 2px 0px red, inset 2px -2px 0px red, inset -2px -2px 0px red;
}

.main {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px blue, inset -2px 2px 0px blue, inset 2px -2px 0px blue, inset -2px -2px 0px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

Эту задачу можно решить, добавив ещё один блок такой же высоты, как и `.header`. Но это не подойдёт, так как в течении всего времени `.header` может изменять свою высоту (с помощью скрипта, изменением ширины и т. д.). При этом `.main` так же должен оставаться под `.header`, а он снова впадёт.

```js
$(function() {
  var $header = $('.header');

  setInterval(function() {
    $header.animate({height: 96 + 'px'}, 400);
      
    setTimeout(function() {
      $header.animate({height: 48 + 'px'}, 400);
    }, 800);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $header.css({height: 'auto'}).animate({right: 80 + '%'}, 400);
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        $header.animate({right: 5 + 'px'}, {
          duration: 400,
          complete: function() {
            $header.css({height: 48 + 'px'})
          }
        });
      }, 800);
    }, 2600);
  }, 5200);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 5px; }

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px red, inset -2px 2px 0px red, inset 2px -2px 0px red, inset -2px -2px 0px red;
}

.main {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px blue, inset -2px 2px 0px blue, inset 2px -2px 0px blue, inset -2px -2px 0px blue;
}

.displacer {
  height: 48px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px green, inset -2px 2px 0px green, inset 2px -2px 0px green, inset -2px -2px 0px green;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="displacer">
</div>
<div class="header">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 48px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 48px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

В общем, вот:

- `.header` может изменять размер, но при этом, `.main` всё равно должен
  оставаться под ним.
- `.header` должен оставаться на своём месте - сверху страницы с `position: fixed`

Как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Сделайте еще один блок совпадающий по размеру с абсолютно позиционированным и поставьте его первым.

Comment: @Visman, я не могу указать такой блок. Элемент с `position absolute;` может иметь разный размер

Comment: Блок с аттрибутом absolute выкидывается с общего потока html посему он всегда будет перекрывать в совем местоположении другие элементы страницы. Единственный вариант изменить его аттрибут для вставки в основной "поток" страницы. flex-block, block etc..

Comment: А почему нельзя менять стили и/или разметку?

Comment: @Qwertiy, суть в том, что делаю не для себя. А там фиг знает, что придёт к тем парням в голову :)

Comment: @Yuri, ну так и делай нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy, как нормально? Уже два дня думаю. Вот Vadim Ovchinnikov скрипт подогнал

Comment: вложи второй блок в первый..

Comment: @Qwertiy, и как это поможет?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61516/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-yuri).

Comment: @Yuri выглядит как будто вы после 2й редакции вопрос полностью поменяли. Может быть, новый зададите?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сама суть вопроса та же. Принятый ответ так же решает данный вопрос. И я, по сути, изменил только absolute на fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте точно такой же элемент только добавьте ему `position: static;` и `visibility: hidden;` (что позволит занимать нужное место, но не отображать элемент).

```css
.a,
.b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}

.a-clone {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a a-clone"></div>
<div class="b">Я не должен быть под красным блоком :с</div>
```

Те же вещи можно делать и с помощью Javascript и также задавать этому "клону" нужные `margin` при необходимости (для соответствующих значений `top` и `left` абсолютно позиционированного элемента).

#### Обновление

Если содержимое блока будет динамически меняться, то можно с помощью Javascript добавить [обработчик изменения размеров](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492683/1548895) самого блока, где присваивать новые значения размеров блока "клону" блока со статическим поционированием.

Comment: Такое вряд ли подойдёт. Понимаете, высоту блоку задаёт его содержимое, а не я. По-этому с изменением размера окна браузера высота будет увеличиваться

Comment: так у вас в клоне будет тоже содержимое, что и блоке абсолют, поэтому добиться одинаковых размеров не проблема....

Answer (score 2):

1. Обернуть фиксированные блоки обертками.
2. По событию `load` брать высоту фиксированных блоков и присваивать ее обертке.
3. Опционально: при динамическом изменении высоты после загрузки вызывать функцию для пересчета высоты `runHeaders`. Чтобы проверить как это работает, разверни на весь экран и потяни браузер за край.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', runHeaders);
window.addEventListener('resize', runHeaders); // для ресайза лучше обернуть функцией debounce

function runHeaders() {
  let headers = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.header')),
      headersF = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.header__fixed'));
    
  headers.forEach((item, index) => {
    heightSetter(item, headersF[index].offsetHeight);
  });
}

function heightSetter(item, height) {
  item.style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.header {
  position: relative;
}

.header__fixed {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  background: #FFF;
}

.main {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=column>
    <div class=header>
      <div class=header__fixed>And if you're</div>
    </div>

    <div class=main></div>
  </div>
  <div class=column>
    <div class=header>
      <div class=header__fixed>hurting I will replace the noise</div>
    </div>

    <div class=main></div>
  </div>
  <div class=column>
    <div class=header>
      <div class=header__fixed>with silence</div>
    </div>

    <div class=main></div>
  </div>
  <div class=column>
    <div class=header>
      <div class=header__fixed>instead flushing out your head</div>
    </div>

    <div class=main></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А разве resize работает на div'ах?

Comment: Не работает на дивах, но вроде бы и не надо в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант #1:

```js
$('body').css('padding-top', $('.header').outerHeight());
$(window).resize(function() {
 $('body').css('padding-top', $('.header').outerHeight());
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  min-height: 48px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px red, inset -2px 2px 0px red, inset 2px -2px 0px red, inset -2px -2px 0px red;
}

.main {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px blue, inset -2px 2px 0px blue, inset 2px -2px 0px blue, inset -2px -2px 0px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Вариант #2:

```js
$('.header-clone').height($('.header').outerHeight());
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.header-clone').height($('.header').outerHeight());
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  min-height: 48px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px red, inset -2px 2px 0px red, inset 2px -2px 0px red, inset -2px -2px 0px red;
}

.header.header-clone {
  position: static;
}

.main {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px blue, inset -2px 2px 0px blue, inset 2px -2px 0px blue, inset -2px -2px 0px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header-clone"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант, если используете препроцессор LESS. Там есть возможность создавать переменную и совершать с ней математические операции, а возможность постоянно находиться под блоком с атрибутом absolute позволит padding-top. Смотрите ссылку на `www.codepen.io` - `https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/BZrRLw`

Как бы ни изменилась высота блока .a, блок .b всегда будет ниже.

Comment: Такое вряд ли подойдёт. Понимаете, высоту блоку задаёт его содержимое, а не я. По-этому с изменением размера окна браузера высота будет увеличиваться

Comment: Неправда. В less нет ничего такого, что былдо бы нельзя сделать без него.