# Шапка закрывает новый блок

Tags: html5, css3

Сделал я себе шапку, получилось почти то что хотел.
Написал блок под header-ом, вписал текст. Проверяю, а его нет. Потом додумался что он под шапкой. Выставил padding 50 и нашёл его. Что за бред постоянно с этими блоками, почему он не снизу шапки появился?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
header{background-color: #000;
    color:#91949f;
    min-height:30px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;}
ul {list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;}
li {float: left;}
li a, .dropbtn, #profil a{color:#bbbab8;font-size:1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;}
.dropdown-content a {
    color:gray;background-color:black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color:gray;color:#fff;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
li a:hover, #profil a:hover{background-color:#2e2f2f;color:#fff;}
#profil{float:right;min-width:100px;}
#tLogo{float: left;padding: 5px;}
.osnova{padding:25px;background-color:gray;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TatuN</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <link href="T.png" rel="chortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <img id="tLogo" src="TTT.jpg" alt="ttt"/>
      <li><a href="#home">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#links">Ссылки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onas">Связь</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Ярлыки</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <div id="profil">
          <a href="">Профиль</a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="osnova"><h1>Тут будет контент страницы</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы дали header position fixed , что по сути выносит его из потока, если хотите использовать position fixed на header , вам по умолчанию нужно дать padding-top всему контенту на каждой странице .
[Ссылка почитать про поток документа](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/potok-dokumenta)

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение ответа выше, скажу, что лучше вам для семантической верстки использовать тег `main`, для удобства дайте вашему `header` фиксированную высоту, что-то вроде `height: 100px;`.
А потом просто добавьте в свой файл стилей `main { padding-top: 100px;}`, не забудьте, что отступ должен быть не меньше высоты вашей шапки, иначе основной контент будет залазить под шапку. А ещё лучше, не использовать `padding`, а использовать `margin`, хотя принципиальной разницы нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если фиксация нужна то к классу osnova добавь:

position: relative;
top: 42px;

Answer (score 0):

Если вы прописываете элементу position:fixed или position:absolute, это выносит этот элемент из общего потока документа. В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686043/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-fixed/688681#688681) с идентичной проблемой можно найти несколько решений.